# Converting int array in string format to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, type-conversion

I have an array of integers stored in string format.

eg:

```
"[3,2,1]"
```

How can I convert this to an actual array?

I've searched high and low for a simple solution but I can't seem to find it.

Passing the string into JSON.parse and $.parseJSON results in "[" being shown for the 0 index. So I'm assuming it's not doing anything.

Comment: Pass the string to `JSON.parse` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've figured out I needed to slice the first and last characters off as for some reason the string was being returned as ""[3,2,1]"" rather than "[3,2,1]" even though it's stored without quotes.

Answer (score 0):

From your updated description it appears you have a string that starts and ends with `"`, so a simple JSON.parse will not work, since that will just convert what's between the `"`'s to a string. You need to either JSON.parse twice, since you have an array of integers embedded in a string, or manually parse.

JSON.parse twice way:

```
var str = '"[3,2,1]"';
var parsedStr = JSON.parse(str); // results in a string with contents [3,2,1]
var intArray = JSON.parse(parsedStr); // results in an int array with contents [3,2,1]
```

Or, if format could change to be non-JSON at some point, manual way:

```
var str = '"[3,2,1]"';
var intArray = [];

str.substr(2,str.length-3).split(/,/g).forEach(function(numStr) {
  intArray.push(parseInt(numStr));
});
```

Comment: As mentioned in my edit JSON.Parse does nothing.
Using your second method the first index is NaN but the others are fine.

Comment: Updated. Sounds like you have a string containing a JSON string containing an int array, not a string containing an int array.

Answer (score 0):

var arr = JSON.parse("[3,2,1]")

Answer (score 0):

```js
var text = "[3,2,1]";
var obj = JSON.parse(text);
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery **[`$.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)** method :

```
var arr = $.parseJSON("[3,2,1]");
```

```js
var str = "[3,2,1]";

console.log( $.parseJSON(str) );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or pure javascript method **[`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)** :

```
var arr = JSON.parse("[3,2,1]");
```

Hope this helps.

```js
var str = "[3,2,1]";

console.log( JSON.parse("[3,2,1]") );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```